# Using list item key to pass data to another component

Tags: reactjs

I am react newbie, struggling to understand concepts, So please be patient before down voting.
I have two components called Editor.js and View.js

Editor.js

```
const Data = [{
    "ID": 101,
    "NAME": "ABC",
},
{
    "ID": 102,
    "NAME": "XYZ",
}
];
//Display list items
<ListGroup>
      {Data.map(function(d, idx){
              return (<ListGroup.Item 
              key={idx.ID}
              >
              {d.NAME}
              </ListGroup.Item>)              
          })}
      </ListGroup>
//Button to View
<Button variant="primary">VIEW</Button>
```

What I want to do is basically use list item Key to get object with similar ID from Data array and pass this object to another component called View.js on onClick event of view button.

Maybe just some explanation for accomplishing it.

Comment: In `map` function first parameter is `current value` in this case your object. Use of key is different than what you are assuming here. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.

Comment: You can simply maintain `selectedIndex`, on click of `listItem` set it and based upon it's value show object from your Data array in your `View.js`.

Comment: Check the basic example https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-browser-39kwx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming users will only be able to view / select a single item from the `<ListGroup>`. If so, the easiest solution would be using component state. Something like:

```
Component .. {
  state = {
    selectedNodeId: null
  }

  render() {
    return(
    ...
    {Data.map((node, i) => (
      <ListGroup.Item
        key={node.id}
        onClick={()=>{this.setState({selectedNodeId: node.id})}
      >
       {node.name}
      </ListGroup.Item>
    ))}
    ...
    <Button to="[take the id from state]">View</Button>
    )
  } 
}
export default ...
```

Comment: Now, when I take the id from state, it returns null every time. Looks like the does not get the updated state. this is what I did `_seeFmu(){
    alert(this.state.selectedFmu);
    }` I am calling that function on onClick of button

Comment: setState uses a callback: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate try to `console.log` the state in a callback and see if it gets updated.